# Weird issue with input element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I came up with a very 'hacky' way to add an icon inside my input box. However no matter what the width of the input box, a portion of the value in the input box is cutt off. I have no idea what could be causing this.

My code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div id="date_range" class="form-control" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <b class="caret"></b><input name="daterange" style="border: none">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried increasing the width of the div my adding:

```
 <div class="pull-right" style="width: 300px">
```

It increases the width of the div but the value is still cutt off:

[image: new]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase the width of the input not the div.

Try:

```
<input name="daterange" style="border: none;width: 95%;">
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: yup solved it. Thanks. I was trying auto earlier which was screwing it up more

Comment: Cool, so please accept the answer with a checkmark, it may help other and it give me good feedback :)

Comment: @newkid101, by the way, @Kld is right, the right way to do this with bootstrap is to use the `input-group`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that in bootstrap is to use an **input-group**

```
<div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          <b class="caret"></b>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`border:none` and `width: 100%` they both don't end with a `;` this could cause the problems your experiencing. however I haven't tested to see if it is.

Try this;

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div id="date_range" class="form-control" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%;">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <b class="caret"></b><input name="daterange" style="border: none; width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your input field has a fixed width. Give it a min-width like 170px or some similar em width. Also check the padding-right on the container element.

Here is a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/zjxborpt/

**HTML**

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div id="date_range" class="form-control">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">ICON</i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <b class="caret">^</b><input type="daterange" name="daterange" class="form-control" style="border: none" value="2016-02-25 - 2016-03-07">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#date_range {
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#date_range i { width: 40px; display: inline-block; } 
#date_range .caret { width: 10px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

#date_range input { min-width: 170px; display: inline-block; }
```